# Как отредактировать файл Python программы?

Tags: python, ipython

Смешной вопрос, наверное... Но я перерыл кучу ссылок и так и не понял, как это можно сделать НЕ выходя из интерпретатора *iPython*. Постараюсь объяснить, что я хочу:

У меня есть куча питон-файлов. Мне нужно их быстро просмотреть и попробовать запустить. Как правило, при вводе команды:

```
ipython program.py
```

выдаётся какое-то сообщение об ошибке. Что бы понять, что оно значит, надо смотреть исходный текст. Я хочу, что бы после запуска *ipython* я мог сделать нечто вроде:

```
%load program.py
%run
%edit
%run
. . . .
```

Но ничего не получается. Ошибка выдаётся при выполнении команды *%load*, а когда я ввожу *%edit*, то запускается *vi*, с пустым(!!!) окном.

Подскажите, как решить эту дурацкую проблему!

Про *PyCharm, Eric,...* я знаю. Но в данной конкретной ситуации использовать IDE неудобно.

Comment: `%edit program.py` ?

Comment: @MaxU Ну да, вроде того... Но всё равно - не удобно. Пока нахожусь в редакторе - не вижу ошибки. Пока нахожусь в интерпретаторе - не вижу исходный текст :-(

Comment: По-моему странная хотелка, не думаю, что что-то удобное найдётся в ipython, ведь для этого изобрели PyCharm)

Comment: ipython notebook Вам в помощь.

Comment: @ Mr Morgan *ipython notebook* - а зачем мне браузер запускать, да ещё и через сервер работать?!

Comment: @andreymal  *для этого изобрели PyCharm* - Отнюдь. Его изобрели для разработки проектов. Когда один и тот же файл смотришь по 8 часов в день (ну, или 2-5 файлов).  А когда надо быстро просмотреть много файлов, оценить их работоспособность, тогда нужно что-то другое.

Comment: Приведу пример из палеолита: когда писали программы на BASIC (просто, без Visual), весь введённый программистом текст запоминался как текст программы.  Загрузить файл программы можно было командой "l". Если я хотел распечатать строки с 10 по 20, то вводил команду 10,20p. Еслю всю программу - просто "р".  Если нужно было запустить программу - набирал команду run. Смотрел ошибки, правил текст с помощью команды "e" и опять запускал на выполнение. И было это всё - в одном окне, ничего не надо было перезапускать, возить мышкой и т.д...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просмотр исходников функции/класса/модуля - `??` после идентификатора:

```
my_module??
```

Просмотр содержимого файла - magic-команда `%pycat`:

`%pycat ./tmp/myscript.py`

Также посмотрите в сторону `%debug` и `%pdb`:

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#debugging

> After an exception occurs, you can call debug to jump into the Python
>   debugger (pdb) and examine the problem. Alternatively, if you call
>   pdb, IPython will automatically start the debugger on any uncaught
>   exception. You can print variables, see code, execute statements and
>   **even walk up and down the call stack** to track down the true source of
>   the problem. This can be an efficient way to develop and debug code,
>   in many cases eliminating the need for print statements or external
>   debugging tools.

Пример отладки через `ipdb`: https://iqbalnaved.wordpress.com/2013/10/17/how-to-debug-in-ipython-using-ipdb/